# Getting a TextBlock/Label in Viewbox to Scale without undesirable padding

Tags: .net, wpf, fonts, viewbox

Here is my very simple xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300" Background="Black" Padding="0" Margin="0" >
    <Viewbox Margin="0">
        <TextBlock Text="Test" Background="AliceBlue" Foreground="Red" 
            Padding="0" Margin="0" />
    </Viewbox>
</Window>
```

This is supposed to scale the Label/Textblock (I've tried both) to fill as much of the window as possible while maintaining aspect ratio of the text.  The issue is, if you drag the size of the window around you can see that there seems to be some sort of invisible, un-changeable padding on the top and bottom of the text.

The left and right don't seem to have it (left image), but the top and bottom do (right image):

[image: Left and Right seem fine.] [image: Left and right, not so much!]

Here I pointed out the extra padding I was talking about:

[image]

I would **expect** it to render more like this (I did this manually, so the aspect ratio is not perfect):

[image]

Has anyone ever overcome this?  Maybe I need to be drawing this text directly with GDI+ or something, but I'm not even sure where to start with that, so any keywords I should hit Google with would also be appreciated!

Comment: Note: you get the same strange padding above and below the text even if you set the `Viewbox` to have `Stretch="Fill"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's part of the font as far as i can tell, try setting `FontFamily` to `Webdings`.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Ewww... so apparently WPF isn't looking at the top and bottom of what is rendered, but instead looks at the height the font tells it it needs?  Hmmm... guess I'll need to find another font, or try to figure out another way to render this stuff (drawing it using GDI+ or something, I guess).

Comment: Well, you could also cut manually using something like negative `Margins` and `ClipToBounds` etc. hardly ideal of course.

Comment: I ended up using something similar to the negative Margins "work-around."  I put my text on a Canvas and set the top negative, and the height to well over 100%.

Comment: That of course is another method, you could also have used a `TranslateTransform`.